# javascript No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, cors

i have deployed a nodejs + express server to heroku, and when i try to use it i get back the error -

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://harel-shop-backend.herokuapp.com/auth/autologin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

in the browser.

this is my app.ts code -

```
import './db/mongoose';
import HttpError from './model/http-error';
import cors from 'cors';

import authRoutes from './routes/auth.router';
import productRouter from './routes/product.router';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization ,AuthorizationRefresh ,user'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE'
  );

  next();
});


app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/products', productRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  throw new HttpError('couldnt find this route', 404);
});

app.use((error: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(error);
  }
  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || 'an unknown error occurred' });
});


app.listen(3030, () => {
  console.log('server is running');
});
```

i have tried to install extensions to my browser to disable cors but didnt work , 
i tried to add the `('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` but also didnt work. 
installed the cors package and used in the line 10 , also didnt work

Comment: Hey @Harelk, it is difficult to answer your question without knowing the exact versions of the packages and what it is that is calling the app. Can you please recreate your app, including the call you are making to it, in a sandbox environment so we can have a look?

Comment: The issue seems to be with OPTIONS preflight - you use both `app.use(cors());` and also add the headers manually - is this an attempt to fix the issue? `app.use(cors());` is usually enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed the problem and i did 2 things ,

1. Made a dist folder with npm build and added a Procfile and wrote there - `web: node dist/app.js`
2. I also added `process.env.PORT || 3030` to the app.listen function